# Calling scopedModel from initState in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have a scopedModel class where I fetch data into it. The thing is that I'm not being able to render this data from InitState method using my scoped model where I have all my api requests. The method is being called but the inside callings are not, so my initial state of the page is not properly shown.

```
void initState() {
    print("Check initState");
    super.initState();
    ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, MainModel model) {
      print("Get into the scoped model");
      model.fecthCars();
      model.fecthCities();
      model.fecthBuys(model.getUserDto.token);
      print(model.getBuys().length);
      return;
    });
  }
```

None of the fetches(Api requests) get called. And the scopedModel returns a widget. I need this to be updated the first time I get into the manager and that's it. No need to call it again. Is this possible? or should I hardcode my api requests in each file I need?

**UPDATE**

If you have your scoped model class set up already you can set a Future like this inside of it

```
mixin MyModel on Model {
    Future<TypeToReturn> methodName(String param) async {
    Uri uri = new Uri.http('serverUrl', 'api/call');

    return await http.get(uri).then((http.Response response) {
      final List<dynamic> myResponse= json.decode(response.body);

      return myResponse;
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Aftermards you can set up your FutureBuilder

```
Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context, MainModel model) {

    return FutureBuilder(
      future:  model.methodName(someString), //This is the method name above
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<TypeToReturn> snapshot) { //type u return
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else {
          if (snapshot.data.length == 0)
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                "No Data Found",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                ),
              ),
            );

          return (create your own widget with the data inside the snapshot)
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Hope this clarify things a little bit more on how I did it.

Comment: What do you need a `StatefulWidget` for when you are using `ScopedModel` anyways

Comment: It's a form and need to call setState methods to show whenever selecting values from a modal.

Comment: if those are `async` methods try to add them in a separate `Future<void>` method and `await` on them, and call this separate method inside `initState`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've a slight misunderstanding about the point of ScopedModel and ScopedModelDescendant. The basic idea of how these should work is that the ScopedModel is created with a valid model which can then be used in other parts of the app.

However, the ScopedModelDescendant should be used within the build() function of a one of your widgets and be part of the widget tree as well. The reason your fetch methods aren't being called is that it isn't in the widget tree so the build function will never be called.

I would recommend instead moving the `fetch` methods out of the model and into some other class (maybe call it a communicator or controller or something). Next, I'd make it so that the model is instantiated as the result of an asynchronous call from that controller.

And finally, rather than instantiating an invalid model then changing the model once the data has been fetched, I'd recommend using a `FutureBuilder` - this way you have control over what to build based on whether the future is underway, successful, or failed.

So that will look something like this (pseudo-code).

```
StatefulWidget (MyApp or whatever you call it)
  build =>
     FutureBuilder(<fetch model data>, ...)
       (if done)
          ScopedModel<MainModel>
             .... (whatever your code has here)
               ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>
                  (build using the model)             
       (if not done)
          Loading.... (if needed)
```

If you absolutely want your model to always be there, I'd still recommend doing the fetching in the top stateful widget and simply changing which model you pass in below it rather than modifying the existing model once the data is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply rmtmckenzie. I'll give it a try and let everyone know how it went. Thought scoped model was used as services in angular to make api calls.

Comment: Yeah in angular there is a scope, but it's quite different than the scoped_model in flutter. In flutter, it's meant as a set of data (model) that happens to be scoped within the widget tree, or at least that's my interpretation of it. Whereas in angular the scope is the binding part between the view and controller.

Comment: I have taken I think a less complex approach. Since you have to define a model for your initial ScopedModel first, I ended up passing this model as an argument to my managers(using routes atributes of my MaterialApp) and fetch  data  on the init state for each one of them. This way I maintain my api  calls in one place  and  can fetch data everytime I got into this part of my code. Thanks a lot  rmtmckenzie.

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled upon the following solution:

In the State Class of my StatefulWidget I do:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // and here...
  MyModel model = ScopedModel.of(context);
  // now I can do with the model whatever I need to do:
  Text someVar = model.initialText;
  model.getValuesFromSomewhere();
  // and so on
}
```

This, in my opinion, is the easiest way of solving the problem as stated by the original Question.

Comment: It's an old question,  but recently I found a new way of doing it by using scopedModelDescendant and FutureBuilder widget, which accepts a future  as an argument and you can use snapshot in your code to handle different states. Did not know about ScopedModel.Of(context) way of using it I will give it a try to see how it works!

Comment: @Matias Any chance you could share code example please.

Comment: I have updated  my answer developer9. Sorry for the delay on my response.

Comment: No worries @Matias. Thanks heaps.

Comment: Attenttion that this solution only works for reading purposes. Because it is not connected to the ScopedModel tree, saving changes wont work.

Answer (score 2):

this is my solution i hope it help

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    User user = ScopedModel.of(this.context);
    _controllerFirstName.text = user.userData['first_name'];
    _controllerLastName.text = user.userData['last_name'];
    }
```